# How to save a JavaDStream as compressed (.gz) file?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, file-comparison

I am new to spark streaming. I am using spark-streaming 2.3.0.
I have a JavaDStream, and I am saving it as a text file, but I want to save it as a compressed(.gz) file.

**Here is my code snipet:**

```
JavaDStream<String> dataStreams = stream.map(new Function<String, String>() {

        public String call(String lines) throws Exception {

            //code


            return lines;
        }

    }  );
dataStreams.dstream().saveAsTextFiles(outputDir, "txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

On each rdd in dstream, call saveAsTextFile() as below:

rdd.saveAsTextFile("Combined", classOf[GzipCodec])

Or at Spark App level:

sc.hadoopConfiguration.setClass(FileOutputFormat.COMPRESS_CODEC, classOf[GzipCodec], classOf[CompressionCodec])

Comment: hi Stivan, thanks for your solution, i am able to save compressed files by rdd.saveAsTextFile("Combined", classOf[GzipCodec]).